# Proving relation for square root of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I represent $\sqrt{1 + ja}$? I'm trying to show that it's approximately equal to $\pm(1 + \frac{ja}{2})$ when $a \leq  1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to use Taylor's theorem at 0; higher order terms are very small, so you can ignore them and keep the linear term only.

That is, take $f(x)=(1+ix)^\frac{1}{2}$ and expand about $x=0$ up to $x^1$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{i}{2}(1+ix)^{-\frac{1}{2}};\\ f''(x)= \frac{1}{4}(1+ix)^{-\frac{3}{2}};\\  f(0)=1, f'(0)=\frac{i}{2}, f''(0)=\frac{1}{4}$$

so $$f(x)= 1+\frac{i}{2}x + \frac{1}{8}x^2+O(x^3)$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ is divided by $2!$ from Taylor's theorem, and the $O(x^3)$ is notation used to denote a function (i.e. the remaining terms in this case) that grows faster, or in this case, equivalently, goes to zero more quickly, than $x^3$.

Comment: I only briefly learned Taylor's theorem years ago, could you show me how to get the first, say, three terms in the series?